# azure File System Usage (App Service Plan)

Tags: azure

Today I noticed what two of my projects on free tire are run out of disk quota.

The projects sizes been less then 400 mb for last year.

How  could I narrow down why  the app hit the file system usage limit?

Comment: Have you looked through your directories under `d:\site`? (easily accessible via kudu - `yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net`) Other than you perusing your file system and finding what's consuming the majority of your space, I'm not sure how anyone will be able to answer that here. And how you solve it (e.g. removing files, offloading to blobs/file storage, database. etc) is really up to you.

Comment: thanks for your replay, I been thinking what where is a common log file which is getting too fat and I just couldn't find it. Turns out it my rep folder :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was checking wwwroot folder. Turned out what D:\home\site\repository folder grew up to 500mb somehow.

You could use du -h {folder} at tools/console

Comment: Have you found some workaround? I have the same case and found that space is mostly used by repository\packages folder even though nuget packages are in .gitignore

Comment: I found what my other applications are using some space too. Azure provides 1gb of space in total. So, there were only two options for me. To use CDN instead of local node_modules folder or update the service plan. I went for the last one. Oh, you also could clean your repository if it is too old and have large files which you don't need anymore